# Send webcam stream from server in Python using sockets

Tags: python, image, sockets, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am trying to send a webcam stream from the `server.py` file to the client.py file using Python sockets. I have it working in the other direction, but want to flip it (the when a client connects to a server, the server will feed webcam data from the server to the client). However, trying to run such results in an error and will only show the first frame of the stream, then crash... What can I do to fix this?

**server.py**

```
import cv2
import io
import socket
import struct
import time
import pickle
import zlib

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 1234))
s.listen(5)

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cam.set(3, 320);
cam.set(4, 240);

img_counter = 0

encode_param = [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 100]

while True:
    client_socket, address = s.accept()
    print(f"Connection from {address} has been established!")

    ret, frame = cam.read()
    result, frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame, encode_param)

    data = pickle.dumps(frame, 0)
    size = len(data)

    print("{}: {}".format(img_counter, size))
    client_socket.send(struct.pack(">L", size) + data)
    print("ooga")
    img_counter += 1

cam.release()
```

**client.py**

```
import socket
import sys
import cv2
import pickle
import numpy as np
import struct ## new
import zlib

HOST=''
PORT=8485

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(),1234))

data = b""
payload_size = struct.calcsize(">L")
print("payload_size: {}".format(payload_size))
while True:
    while len(data) < payload_size:
        print("Recv: {}".format(len(data)))
        data += s.recv(4096)

    print("Done Recv: {}".format(len(data)))
    packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
    data = data[payload_size:]
    msg_size = struct.unpack(">L", packed_msg_size)[0]
    print("msg_size: {}".format(msg_size))
    while len(data) < msg_size:
        data += s.recv(4096)
    frame_data = data[:msg_size]
    data = data[msg_size:]

    frame=pickle.loads(frame_data, fix_imports=True, encoding="bytes")
    frame = cv2.imdecode(frame, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    cv2.imshow('ImageWindow',frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that will work:

Client.py

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import socket
import sys
import pickle
import struct

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
clientsocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('localhost',8089))

while True:
    ret,frame=cap.read()
    # Serialize frame
    data = pickle.dumps(frame)

    # Send message length first
    message_size = struct.pack("L", len(data)) ### CHANGED

    # Then data
    clientsocket.sendall(message_size + data)
```

Server.py

```
import pickle
import socket
import struct

import cv2

HOST = ''
PORT = 8089

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print('Socket created')

s.bind((HOST, PORT))
print('Socket bind complete')
s.listen(10)
print('Socket now listening')

conn, addr = s.accept()

data = b'' ### CHANGED
payload_size = struct.calcsize("L") ### CHANGED

while True:

    # Retrieve message size
    while len(data) < payload_size:
        data += conn.recv(4096)

    packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
    data = data[payload_size:]
    msg_size = struct.unpack("L", packed_msg_size)[0] ### CHANGED

    # Retrieve all data based on message size
    while len(data) < msg_size:
        data += conn.recv(4096)

    frame_data = data[:msg_size]
    data = data[msg_size:]

    # Extract frame
    frame = pickle.loads(frame_data)

    # Display
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Hope this suites your needs!!

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

The following does what you want. On the server-side (in this case a raspberry pi) you bind to a port and wait for connections:

```
#!/bin/python
import io, struct
import picamera
import socket

STREAMING_PORT = 8887

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:

    stream = io.BytesIO()
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', STREAMING_PORT))
    server_socket.listen(2)

    while True:
        client_conn, client_address = server_socket.accept()
        connection = client_conn.makefile('wb')

        print ("Accepted connection")
        for _ in camera.capture_continuous(stream, 'jpeg', use_video_port = True):
            try:
                connection.write(struct.pack('<L', stream.tell()))
                connection.flush()
                stream.seek(0)
                connection.write(stream.read())
                stream.seek(0)
                stream.truncate()
           
            except:
                break
                
    connection.close()
    server_socket.close()
```

On the desktop side (the client), you open a connection to the server and get streaming. Of course you will have to know the address of your server.

```
#!/bin/python
import socket
import cv2
import numpy as np

PI_IP = "192.168.0.100"
STREAMING_PORT = 8887

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect((PI_IP, STREAMING_PORT))

client_socket.settimeout(5)
client_socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, True)
        
rfile = client_socket.makefile('rb')
stream_bytes = b' '

while True:
    stream_bytes += rfile.read(1024)
            
    if len(stream_bytes) == 0:
        break

    first = stream_bytes.find(b'\xff\xd8')
    last = stream_bytes.find(b'\xff\xd9')
            
    if first != -1 and last != -1:

        jpg = stream_bytes[first:last+2]
        stream_bytes = stream_bytes[last+2:]

        image = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
        cv2.imshow('image', image)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
rfile.close()
client_socket.close()
```

You may also be interested in creating a generator on the client side, for instance if you are relaying the stream.

```
                yield b'--frame\r\n'
                yield b'X-Timestamp: %s\r\n' % str(time.time()).encode()
                yield b'Content-Length: %s\r\n' % str(len(jpg)).encode()
                yield b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' 
                yield jpg
                yield b'\r\n'
```